# How can I set a max length for a string value in a XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, report, birt

I'm trying to modify this XML that was generated by a Toolkit software.
I need to set a max length for a value (string) in this file.

I tried to use the `MaxLength="10"` property and `lenght="10"`. They didn't work :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>
    <name>REPORT</name>
    <description>Elenco Pratiche</description>
    <engine format="XLS" name="BIRT">
        <template>REPORT.rptdesign</template>
    </engine>
    <onlinePage/>
    <PARAS>
        <name dataType="String" displayName="Business Unit"
            displayType="text-box" inputdefault="SYS_BU_CODE" property="P">ISP_BUSI_UNIT</name>
        <name dataType="String" displayName="UO Pratica"
            displayType="text-box" inputdefault="" length="8" property="O">C_UNIT_CODE</name>
        <name FCRule="GTEE_TYPE_IMPEGNO" dataType="String" displayName="Tipo Impegno"
            displayType="list-box" inputdefault="" isSingle="true" property="O">GTEE_TYPE_IMPEGNO</name>
    </PARAS>
    <MAIL_RULE/>
</report>
```

I need to set this max length for the field "C_UNIT_CODE".
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need a XML-Schema-Definition (XSD). Then you create a `simpleType` and set the maxLength

```
<xs:simpleType name="C_UNIT_CODE">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:maxLength value="12"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I need to use this format because the server expects a xml file like the one I posted...

Comment: You can embed a XSD into a XML file. That's called an inline XML schema. There are multiple approaches. Do you know what XML validator the target system uses? (examples: `XSV`, `.NET`,..)